# Qual a melhor maneira de se representar um Endereço?

Tags: banco-de-dados, usabilidade, modelagem, normalização

Ao modelar **endereços** em uma aplicação, ingenuamente segui a forma normalizada ao representar no BD (i.e. tabelas separadas para **país**, **estado**, **cidade**, **bairro** etc - *joins* para todo lado), e na interface de usuário (html) coloquei um campo separado para cada parte desse endereço (caixa de texto com autocompletar ou *combo box*). No começo achava que estava bom desse jeito, e não pensei muito no assunto.

Entretanto, após fazer [uma pergunta no UX.SE](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/33986/15436) (relativo ao nosso padrão de usar "Rua X" em vez de "X street") as respostas me levaram a questionar se valia a pena na prática exigir tamanho nível de detalhe na representação. Além da complexidade adicional na hora de buscar/atualizar (como exemplificado [nessa "pirâmide"](http://pastebin.com/5N8z3B5y)), não sei como a performance do sistema será quando ele contiver um número elevado de endereços.

Gostaria de saber, de quem já tem **experiência** lidando com um grande número de endereços, quais práticas seriam recomendadas: deixar tudo normalizado, usar um campo de texto aberto, condensar algumas tabelas numa só (ex.: `cidade_estado_pais`) e deixar outras separadas, etc. Levando em consideração que:

- Poucos usuários entrarão com muitos endereços, **de outras pessoas** (se fosse cada usuário entrando com o próprio endereço uma vez e pronto, não justificaria investir em usabilidade).
- Se uma parte do endereço já existe no banco (ex.: uma rua previamente cadastrada) o autocompletar pode ser usado para agilizar a entrada de dados; isso seria mais difícil se o endereço fosse um campo aberto.
- Alguns dados são mais fáceis de encontrar e pré-popular (ex.: lista completa de cidades brasileiras), outros são mais difíceis ou [mais caros](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/400) - podendo ser melhor que o usuário entre com eles sob demanda (mas ainda permitindo autocompletar).
- Se um campo é aberto, fica mais sujeito a duplicação (ex.: "Av Foo", "Av. Foo", "Avenida Foo", "A. Foo", "Foo"); mas duplicação [não é necessariamente um problema](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/33998/15436)...
- É mais difícil fazer agregação em um campo desnormalizado (ex.: se quero estatísticas por estado, mas agrupei `cidade_estado_pais` num campo só, terei problemas).

Comment: Nota: sei que uma solução "ótima" varia caso-a-caso (conforme a aplicação), mas não estou buscando simplesmente **opiniões**, na qual toda resposta é válida - gostaria de ouvir de quem tem **experiência** lidando com sistemas que contém um grande número de endereços, por exemplo para evitar problemas que não podem ser antecipados quando sua base é pequena, só aparecem depois que ela já cresceu em escala.

Comment: Não entendo o que está perguntando. É sobre modelagem dos dados (banco de dados) ou sobre usabilidade (interface com o usuário)??

Comment: @talles A pergunta é sobre **modelagem**, embora as diferentes decisões de representação (normalizar, não normalizar) acabam por ter um grande impacto na usabilidade. Em outras palavras, achei importante citar considerações de usabilidade aqui para ajudar a orientar numa resposta adequada.

Comment: https://www.mjt.me.uk/posts/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-addresses/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Na minha opinião o melhor banco de dados de endereços do Brasil é o e-DNE que possui mais de 900 mil registros e, na minha opinião, funciona bem rápido.
Segue o diagrama do banco deles.
[image: Diagrama e-DNE correios]

Quando precisei usar esse banco achei bem simples fácil e rápido, acredito que servirá para seus propósitos e claro que esse banco do correio é bem complexo pois abrange muitas coisas mas você pode reduzi-lo para seus propósitos.

[Aqui](http://www.correios.com.br/Produtosaz/complementos/pdf/Base_eDNE.zip) você pode baixar um zip com o modelo do banco e um arquivo doc que explica bem direitinho como ele funciona. 
Então acho que não precisa reinventar a roda, vamos nos espelhar nos melhores...

Agora na questão endereço duplicado e dados duplicados em geral, a melhor maneira de resolver isso é um algoritmo bem inteligente que vá comparar os dados fornecidos e cruzar com informações para tentar unificar as informações.

Recomendo ler esse [Link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm), e boa sorte afinal não é uma tarefa simples, mas conseguindo os resultados esperado é muito gratificante.

Comment: Obrigado pela sugestão, vou ler a documentação indicada. De fato, se há um modelo padronizado e amplamente utilizado há muitas vantagens em se utilizá-lo, por exemplo na interoperabilidade com outros sistemas que também o usem.

Comment: Caramba, dei só uma leitura rápida e já achei um erro grave na **minha** modelagem: estava representando "bairro" e "logradouro" numa relação `1:N`, mas uma rua pode passar por vários bairros! Um par `(logradouro, número)` sim pertence a um único bairro, mas o logradouro pertence à cidade e não ao bairro. Já vi que esse padrão será muito útil e instrutivo a "leigos" como eu (que ainda que possua uma noção "intuitiva" de endereços, ainda consigo cometer tais erros na hora de "botar no papel").

Comment: que bom que ajudou, eu percebi que a grande jogada desse banco dos correios é a forma que ele armazena o cep, separando o CEP certinho você consegue consultar bem rápido exatamente onde você quer.

Answer (score 14):

No nosso caso, a forma como os dados são organizados está diretamente ligada ao uso dos mesmos para facilitar o seu preenchimento, recolha e análise, ou seja:

1. Se vamos efetuar pesquisas ou elaborar estatísticas sobre determinada informação, essa informação deve estar separada:

   Estatísticas sobre a localidade da pessoa, obriga a que o campo `localidade` esteja numa coluna só para ele.

   **Exemplo:** `Coimbra`
2. Se o campo não é relevante para pesquisas ou estatísticas, o campo pode estar junto com outra informação:

   O caso das ruas onde a  pessoa reside, que podem ter nomes curtos ou compridos, mas não estando sujeitos a análises, podem ficar numa só coluna:

   **Exemplo:** `Av. da Liberdade` ou `Avenida da Liberdade` é igual. Resume-se a texto que separado em duas colunas, uma para o tipo de rua e outra para o nome da rua só vai gerar confusão na hora de preencher e/ou recolher essa informação.

---

Ter tudo separado se não existe proveito é desnecessário. Ter tudo junto e depois necessitar de analisar os dados em separado também não faz sentido.

O que tentamos fazer é apurar que dados são mais comuns e fáceis de gerir em separado. Depois cruzamos essa resultado com os dados que já sabemos que vão estar sujeitos a análises, tendo em conta os que poderão no futuro vir a estar também sujeitos a análise.

Com o resultado, temos uma boa ideia de como devemos guardar toda a informação.

Por outro lado, também temos que considerar o uso de tabelas secundárias, como é o caso dos países. Não faz sentido um utilizador ter que escrever o nome do seu país se no mundo inteiro existem X países e esse número é raro mudar, faz todo o sentido ter uma tabela secundária com os países e o utilizador apenas tem que selecionar o seu.

Comment: Acho que tem razão, mas vou esperar um pouco mais. Gostaria de ouvir de quem já passou por essa situação mas errou no julgamento (i.e. achou que não ia precisar da análise no futuro, precisou, e teve que fazer ajustes). Se foi tranquilo de migrar os dados, se surgiram problemas...

Answer (score 9):

Trabalhando em um projeto gigantesco, percebi que não é possível fugir muito dessa forma de tratar esse paradigma, deixando cada tabela separada por logradouro, bairro, cidade...etc. Algo importante é sempre manter índices em todas as tabelas e otimizar suas consultas, hoje fazemos também um filtro, para que o usuário seja mais específico na busca caso traga muitos resultados, minha equipe de desenvolvimento está remodelando o sistema do zero começando pelo BD, a priori isso é a experiência que tive, caso ao chegarmos nesta parte da modelagem do banco, e algo for modificado eu terei o maior prazer em vir nesta pergunta e demonstrar para ter algo mais concreto para ti, espero que mesmo que pouco tenha contribuído...

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta! No seu caso, vocês separam o logradouro do seu tipo (Rua, Avenida, etc) ou é tudo um campo só?

Comment: Por enquanto utilizamos tudo junto somente: Rua X, Avenida Y...

Comment: Por enquanto somente fica junto o tipo de logradouro e o nome dele, o restante tudo tem uma tabela própria.

Comment: Bom saber, pois de fato essa é a parte que traz mais problema (na minha implementação incial fiz isso separado também), estou mesmo inclinado a juntar. Acredito que os casos de duplicação (Rua X, R. X) são tranquilos de resolver, ainda mais quando os endereços são informados por funcionários treinados e não pelo público em geral, certo? (ou você não chegou a experimentar esse problema - por exemplo, por usar listas de logradouros pré-populados?)

Comment: Cara, se você não vai ter este problema de qualquer pessoa inserir, acho altamente recomendável manter junto mesmo, pois no meu caso é o contrário, trabalho com uma plataforma de e-commerce, ou seja, os usuários é que se cadastram, vira uma bagunça, tudo duplicado, no seu caso acho válido manter junto...

Answer (score 8):

> Gostaria de saber, de quem já tem experiência lidando com um grande número de endereços, quais práticas seriam recomendadas: deixar tudo normalizado, usar um campo de texto aberto, condensar algumas tabelas numa só (ex.: cidade_estado_pais) e deixar outras separadas, etc.

Na empresa em que trabalho sou responsável por um serviço que consolida endereços de vários outros sistemas. Já que você citou a questão da experiência grande parte do que falarei aqui é experiência/opnião minha.

## » Normalizar ou não?

Normalize. A ser não ser o que esteja fazendo seja extretamente simplório, recomendo normalizar os dados. A consistência dos dados não só lhe livrará de futuros problemas (fica, por exemplo, mais díficil inserir um endereço inválido) como também evitará um *engessamento* destes dados (um eventual relatório ou integração com outro sistema que possui esses dados normalizados).

## » Agregar tabelas?

Não vejo necessidade. A única possibilidade de agregar tabelas que vejo é no exemplo que você citou (cidade-estado-país). Se modeladas corretamente um eventual *join* ou pesquisa não gerará um *overhead* significante.

## » Tipo do logradouro?

Existem sistemas que dedicam uma coluna própria para o tipo do logradouro do endereço (avenida, rua, alameda, etc). Não acho importante fazê-lo a não ser que seja realmente necessário.

Pense, por exemplo, como extrair essa informação fornecida pelo usuário. Ou fazes um *select* (*drop down list*) e força o usuário selecionar um tipo de logradouro correto (o que não é muito funcional/agradável) ou tenta extrair essa informação do campo logradouro (o que pode ser complicado fazer corretamente ou deixar o fluxo travado).

## » Como modelar afinal?

Segue exemplo prático do serviço que mencionei. A base real possuí centenas de milhares de endereços.

Tabela `Endereco`:

- `CEP`: PK da tabela. Campo com exatamente 8 caracteres. Sempre sem máscara.
- `Logradouro`: Incluso o tipo do logradouro e o número do endereço.
- `Bairro`
- `Localidade`: Cidade. Possuí índice.
- `UF`: Campo com exatamente 2 caracteres. É uma FK para a tabela de unidades federativas.
- `Data`: Data de cadastro/atualização do endereço.

Tabela `Unidade Federativa`

- `Sigla`: PK da tabela. Campo com exatamente 2 caracteres. Sigla do estado.
- `Nome`: Nome completo do estado.

## » Cargas iniciais

Recomendo apenas para unidade federativa e cidade. *Unidade federativa* é rarissímo haver mudanças. *Cidade* já é mais comum haver mudanças mas nada que não seja possível de manter. Qualquer campo mais localizado, como *Bairro*, já passa a ser difícil manter uma carga.

*Obs.*: Me refiro a dados que não são inseridos pelos usuários. Dados esses *estáticos* mantidos pelo próprio sistema (muitas vezes de forma manual pelos próprios desenvolvedores). Por isso a recomendação de fazer somente com *cidade* e *unidade federativa*.

## » Pesquisa a coluna? Índice!

Lembre-se de criar índice nas colunas em que você pesquisa nelas (ex: autocomplete de bairros).

## » Cada caso é um caso

As recomendações que deixo são para banco de dados relacionais e endereços do Brasil. Lembre-se de adaptar-se e colocar seu próprio conhecimento e crítica ao modelar seu sistema. Afinal, *cada caso é um caso*.

Comment: "como também evitará um engessamento destes dados" aí está algo que não tinha pensado, obrigado por chamar a atenção a essa possibilidade. Vejo também que concorda com os demais que a normalização é desejável (e não acarreta problemas de desempenho se feita corretamente), exceto pelo logradouro e tipo - que podem ser mantidos num campo só. Já estou fortemente inclinado nesse sentido.

Comment: Numa segunda leitura, me surgiu uma dúvida: existe alguma razão para **não fazer** carga inicial de cidades, bairros, logradouros, etc? OK, isso muda, mas se esses dados viessem do usuário eles não estariam sujeitos ao mesmo problema? No meu caso, tenho acesso a uma base bastante desatualizada (2005+/-) de logradouros, mas ainda que uma porcentagem dos mesmos esteja incorreta creio que corrigi-los sob demanda é menos custoso que impor aos clientes (e é mais de um, com bases independentes) começar tudo do zero - o que também abre a possibilidade de erros. Concorda, ou algo está me escapando?

Comment: @mgibsonbr Não vejo problema. O problema é quando você tenta por conta própria manter esses dados atualizados. Vou editar minha resposta para clarear o que quis dizer.